# Удаление несколько обработчиков событий

Tags: javascript

Как грамотнее удалять несколько событий в JS первым или вторым способом ?

Я совсем чайник в js, чувствую что неправильно оформил код.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');   

function first(){
alert('Первое событие');    
}

function second(){
alert('Второе событие');    
}

a.addEventListener("click", first);
a.addEventListener("click", second);

// a.removeEventListener("click", first, second) - первый вариант удаления

// a.removeEventListener("click", first)         - второй вариант удаления
// a.removeEventListener("click", second)        - второй вариант удаления
```

```css
#block{
background: orange;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#texts{
font-size: 25px;
padding:12px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">                  
<div id ="texts">
Удаление несколько событий
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Первый вариант удаления не работает, так как обработчик событий может быть только вторым аргументом, а третий - опции.

Comment: Остается только второй вариант?
А если обработчиков будет много?
Есть ли какой-нибудь еще более удобный способ удаления?

Comment: Ну можно написать какую-то свою обертку, которая будет убирать сразу несколько, дергая `removeEventListener` для каждого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const removeEventListeners = (element, eventName, listeners) =>
  listeners.forEach(listener => element.removeEventListener(eventName, listener));

removeEventListeners(a, 'click', [first, second]);
```

Если надо удалять много обработчиков ^

Comment: forEach, если мне не изменяет память это метод массива? Вы положили две функции в массив? А в удалении использовали родительскую функцию стрелку и дочернюю функцию стрелку? Я чего-то не понимаю, можно более подробное объяснение вашего кода))) Но лайкос за ответ уже поставил =)

Comment: да, все верно. создал функцию (removeEventListeners) которая будет удалять не нужные мне обработчики. Ей надо знать елемент, название события, и канешно же названия обработчиков(first, second, etc). 
Так как нам надо удалять больше одного обработчика то можно передавать их масивом что позволяет использовать методы перебора (например форич). Дальше нам надо просто пройтись по масиву с обработчиками и сказать DOM елементу (element) что для события что мы передали (eventName) надо удалить  каждый елемент масива (element.removeEventListener(eventName, listener)).

Comment: Благодарю, а что за имена element, eventName, listeners, listener ?? За что они отвечают и что это?

Comment: Вам сюда https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions и сюда https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. Удачи в учебе:)